# Why doesn't the XmlSerializer need the type to be marked [Serializable]?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

In C#, if I want to serialize an instance with `XmlSerializer`, the object's type doesn't have to be marked with `[Serializable]` attribute. However, for other serialization approaches, such as `DataContractSerializer`, needs the class be marked as `[Serializable]` or `[DataContract]`.

Is there any standard or pattern about serialization requirement?

Answer (score 20):

This is because XmlSerializer only serializes public fields/properties. Other forms of serialization can serialize private data, which constitutes a potential security risk, so you have to "opt in" using an attribute.

Comment: Making fields/properties public only for serialization purpose - that is security risk. Nothing bad about serializing private fields

Answer (score 8):

Security isn't the only issue; simply, serialization only makes sense for certain classes. For example, it makes little snse to serialize a "connection". A connection **string**, sure, but the connection itself? nah. Likewise, anything that requires an unmanaged pointer/handle is not going to serialize very well. Nor are delegates.

Additionally, `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` (by default) are *tree* serializers, not *graph* serializers - so any recursive links (like `Parent`) will cause it to break.

Marking the class with the serializer's preferred token is simply a way of saying "and it should make sense".

IIRC, both `[XmlSerializer` and `[DataContractSerializer]` **used** to be **very** rigid about demanding things like `[Serializable]`, `[DataContract]` or `[IXmlSerializable]`, but they have become a bit more liberal lately.

Comment: True, and this is a good argument as to why XmlSerializer SHOULD require attributes too... there's nothing stopping you from serializing something that doesn't make sense. But I think security was the main reason they DIDN'T do this.

Comment: And AFAIK, XmlSerializer never required any attributing, at least back to .NET 1.1, although you could always control it with the various Xml* attributes and IXmlSerializable.

Comment: common misconception:  Xml Serializer never required [Serializable] and was never associated with [Serializable].  The [Serializable] attribute never had any effect on the actions or behavior of the Xml Serializer.  They have always been unrelated, except in people's minds!

Comment: @Cheeso - probably because my first use of XmlSerializer was via asmx services, does that require it>

Comment: AFAIR, SOAP serialization does require [Serializable]. But SOAP serialization is very different from XML serialization.

Comment: @Anton: No such thing as SOAP Serialization. That's runtime serialization using the SOAP formatter.

Answer (score 4):

Right now there are really 3 forms of serialization in the .Net Framework.

1. XmlSerialization - By default works on public fields and properties.  Can still be controlled via XmlElementAttribute, XmlAttributeAttribute, etc ...
2. BinarySerialization - Controlled by the SerializationAttribute.  Deeply integrated into the CLR
3. WCF Seralization - DataContractAttribute, etc ...

There unfortunately is standard overall pattern for serialization.  All 3 frameworks have different requirements and quirks.

Comment: You might want to add JavaScriptSerializer to that list - different requirements and quirks, but part of the core framework now.

Comment: @Marc, hadn't heard about that one before.  Will have to look into it.

Comment: JP - typo?  s/Serialization/Serializable.  The key point here is that [Serializable] is an attribute that is meaningful to the binary serializer, and the Xml Serializer doesn't use it.  Conversely, [XmlElement] is used by the latter, and the former doesn't use i.

Comment: IIRC, Serializer was created to support MarshalByRefObject / .NET Remoting, XmlSerializer was created to support ASMX web services, and DataContractSerializer was created to support WCF, hence the inconsistencies. :-)