# Prevent XmlSerializer from auto instantiating List's on Deserialize

Tags: c#, deserialization, xmlserializer

Assuming I have this sample class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<int> ListTest { get; set; }
    public string StringTest { get; set; }
    public int IntTest { get; set; }
}
```

And this code:

```
string xmlStr = "<MyClass><StringTest>String</StringTest></MyClass>";
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
using (XmlReader reader = xml.CreateReader())
{
    var res = ser.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

After the Deserialize is completed the value of `res` is:
`ListTest` -> Empty List with Count = 0 (**NOT null**).
`StringTest` -> "String" as expected
`IntTest` -> 0 as expect (default value of an integer).

I'd like the serializer to act the same (`default(List<T>)` which **is null**) with List's and not instantiate them.

How can I accomplish something like that?
BTW, I **must** use the `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use backup-property to serialize/deserialize property as array:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<int> ListTest { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ListTest")]
    public int[] _listTest
    {
        get { return ListTest?.ToArray(); }
        set { ListTest = value == null ? null : new List<int>(value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Making `ListTest` private and using it as backing field would be better.

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz, there [are problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4314982/1997232) to serialize `private` members with `XmlSerializer`. As for a backfield of `List<T>` type suggestion, exposing `T[]` property (with `list.ToArray()` in the getter?) is expensive, I wouldn't do it in general. The idea here is to only tune serialization, leaving `public List<T>` property without changes, because I have no clues about its usage scenarios (maybe it's big, maybe property is called often, maybe it's set often, etc.)

Comment: I've suggested to make it private because it will not be serialized already since it has `[XmlIgnore]` attribute.