# Privately declared properties in C# don't show up in TypeScript in SPA

Tags: properties

So, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here but for some reason the callback function in TypeScript that i have doesn't have anything but _proto in the response's .data property whenever i set private properties in C# and new up an object that is filled with constructed properties.  However, if the properties are public and i don't use a constructor then i can see the response's .data property is filled like i would expect it to be.  Here is an example of what works:

```
public class ThisWorks{
   public string MyProperty{get;set;}
}
```

Inside application layer:

```
ThisWorks example = new ThisWorks();
example.MyProperty = myReflectedProperty;
return example;
```

However, this does not work:

```
public class ThisDoesNotWork{
  private string MyPrivateProperty {get;set;}
    public ThisDoesNotWork(string myPrivateProperty){
        MyPrivateProperty = myPrivateProperty;
     }
 }
```

What's causing this to happen?  My TypeScript service has not changed but for some reason the data isn't coming across from the service call...Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you use to serialize your c# object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# serialize private class member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314982/c-sharp-serialize-private-class-member). Follow the thread in that question. It should get you where you need to go.

Comment: I didn't serialize in either case.  Also, i forgot to mention i'm using TypeScript, actually.  If you're going to say "add a serializer" then please don't as that is not helpful.

Comment: Then post the code that ships your c# object over to the client.

Comment: If you are returning your c# object from the application layer to the client, like in your snippet, you must be serializing it.

Comment: Hey, just try to make a public property and send it across like i did.  I think you'll be VERY SURPRISED to know it WORKS!  But, if you never try, then you'll never know...it's up to you if you want to figure it out or not, i can't make you do it...