# PostSharp How to know at runtime if a certain aspect was applied to a method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, aop, postsharp

I'm implementing a PostSharp aspect library and can't find out a solution to the following problem.

Suppose we have an aspect that will be applied for some methods and won't be applied for the others. I need some mechanism that I can use at runtime to know whether an aspect was applied to a method. Specifically, **what is the recommended way to determine at runtime whether certain aspect was applied to a particular method given by a `System.Reflection.MethodBase`?**

The first solution that comes into my head is to make PostSharp mark every method that has been modified by this aspect with a custom atribute and use `methodBase.CustomAttributes` at runtime. Is this the right solution for the problem? Or maybe there already is a ready-to-use or more elegant solution in PostSharp.

Also, please take into account that preferred is a solution that doesn't require a paid PostSharp license since Free Community Edition is enough for my current project. Anyway, it would be very intresting to discuss solutions based on paid PostSharp functionality too.

Comment: what kind of aspects are we talking about? If you inherit for example from methodInterceptionAttribute then you can add the [MyAttribute] to the method and it would be applied to just the methods you specify. would this be sufficient?

Comment: postsharp applies attributes compile time. why would you need to determine at runtime if a attribute has been applied.

Comment: @Batavia, My current situation is about the `OnExceptionAspect`, but I'm wondering how to implement this regerdless of a specific aspect type. There is `PostSharp.Post.IsTransformed` to determine at runtime If the assembly has been transformed. I'm searching something like this but for single methods.

Comment: @Batavia, However, could you please point to a solution to mark a method with an attribute using `MethodInterceptionAspect` specifically? All I could find is how to inject attributes using IAspectProvider, for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7852177/3345644). Additionally, this approach requires paid Composite Attribute feature of PostSharp.

Comment: @Batavia, Answering to your second comment, one of the use cases of the aspects library I'm implementing is that when an exception occures, I need to log full stack trace with parameter values of every method that was transformed by my aspect skipping other methods in the stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're adding a method-level aspect (e.g. [OnExceptionAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_onexceptionaspect)) as an attribute on the class or the assembly level, PostSharp [*multicasts*](http://doc.postsharp.net/multicast) this attribute to all the applicable methods in that class/assembly. At the next stage the aspect transforms each method with the attribute and the attribute itself is removed.

You can tell PostSharp to keep all the aspect attributes by setting the [MulticastAttributeUsageAttribute.PersistMetaData](http://doc.postsharp.net/multicast-reflection) property to *true*. The [`[MulticastAttributeUsage]`](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_extensibility_multicastattributeusageattribute) attribute must be applied to your aspect class.

```
[MulticastAttributeUsage( PersistMetaData = true )]
public class MyAspect : OnExceptionAspect
{
    // ...
}
```

Now you can look for `MyAspect` in `MethodBase.CustomAttributes` to determine whether the aspect has been applied to the current method.

Comment: Quick note for anyone in my situation - the attribute is never retained on the class itself, only on the methods within in