# Enable session for complete webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, session

I have a web service. I have around 15 web methods in it. Now I want to use session variables. To enable session we can use WebMethodAttribute.EnableSession Property like below for each web method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string GetSomeDetails() {}
```

But instead of writing for all web methods, I want to do it in only one place. So is there any way to enable session for complete WebService.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in solution for this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852177/4444410) is a postsharp solution.