# Why doesn't the class need to be marked with either the [DataContract] or [Serializable] attributes to be serialized?

Tags: c#, serialization

Microsoft provides code in its article, "[How to serialize an object to XML by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813)."

```
using System;

public class clsPerson
{
  public  string FirstName;
  public  string MI;
  public  string LastName;
}

class class1
{ 
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      clsPerson p=new clsPerson();
      p.FirstName = "Jeff";
      p.MI = "A";
      p.LastName = "Price";
      XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
      x.Serialize(Console.Out, p);
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

However, why doesn't the class, clsPerson, need to be marked with either the [DataContract] or [Serializable] attributes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the XmlSerializer need the type to be marked \[Serializable\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392431/why-doesnt-the-xmlserializer-need-the-type-to-be-marked-serializable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx) doesn't require those attributes to be placed on the class. Only [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.SerializableAttribute.aspx) and [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) do. And for that matter, `DataContractSerializer` can do without.

See related question: [Why is Serializable Attribute required for an object to be serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982376/why-is-serializable-attribute-required-for-an-object-to-be-serialized)

Answer (score 4):

By design, XML serialization serializes public fields and public properties with get AND set accessor. The serialized type must also have a parameterless constructor. It's the only contract \o/