# Make an object serializable at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

Is there a way to make serializable an object at runtime? Should I use Reflection?

Note: the object is part of an external library, so I do not have the source code for it.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "making serializable". What _exactly_ are you trying to do?

Comment: add the [Serializable] attribute to the class

Comment: Now that is a specific question you can search for. See [Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr - No.

While you can use `TypeDescriptor` to add attributes to anything at runtime, in the context of the `Serializable` attribute it won't help since `BinaryFormatter` uses classic reflection and not `TypeDesciptor` reflection.

The idea behind that attribute is for the serializable class to opt-in to being serializable. More details about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982376/why-is-serializable-attribute-required-for-an-object-to-be-serialized).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure you could possibly use a serializer which is not opt-in i.e. it does not require any attribute on the target class, for example the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).