# Why can I still serialize classes without the attribute [System.SerializableAttribute()]?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm playing with serialization (specifically XmlSerializer) and am slightly confused.

The class I intend to serialize has the attribute:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
```

This is great, but when I derive from the class, I can still serialize the derived class?
This is odd because I thought attributes weren't inherited to the derived class?

Secondly, to compound my confusion, I created just a standard class that didn't inherit from anything, nor did I mark it with any attributes, and I could still serialize it?

Comment: XmlSerializer doesn't need SerializableAttribute to serialize objects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392431/why-doesnt-the-xmlserializer-need-the-type-to-be-marked-serializable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SerializableAttribute` does not affect `XmlSerializer`. This attribute is for other serialization formats such as the [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx).