# Deserialize xml elements along with nodes into a string property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following xml

```
  <Amendment.Text>
    <Page>4</Page>
    <Line>4</Line>
    <Bold>It is a </Bold>   
    <Italic>Beautiful Day</Italic>
    <Bold>In London</Bold>
    <Italic>17 June 2015</Italic>   
</Amendment.Text>
```

I want to retrieve the `<Bold>` and `<Italic>` elements into a 
string property

Output (String property content):

```
<Bold>It is a </Bold>   
    <Italic>Beautiful Day</Italic>
    <Bold>In London</Bold>
    <Italic>17 June 2015</Italic>
```

My serializable class is as below -

```
[Serializable]
    public class AmdTextType
    {

        public string Page { get; set; }

        public string Line { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

    }
```

I am able to deserialize `Page` and `Line` but not able to get the 
`Italic` and `Bold` elements with the tag

Comment: It's unclear what problem do you have, there is no `Italic` nor `Bold` properties in `AmdTextType` class. Do you use `XmlSerialier`? Then you [don't need to use `[Serializable]`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/392431/1997232).

Answer (score 2):

Could this not be:

```
  <Amendment.Text>
    <Page>4</Page>
    <Line>4</Line>
    <Content>CDATA(["
       <Bold>It is a </Bold>   
       <Italic>Beautiful Day</Italic>
       <Bold>In London</Bold>
       <Italic>17 June 2015</Italic>   
    "])
    </Content>
</Amendment.Text>
```

Comment: This would have solved the issue but we don't have control over the xml format.

Comment: I think you have a problem then. The only way I can think of is reading the string manually, all XML Deserialisers are going to try and parse the Bold and Italic lines as tags and match them to IEnumerables (if you're lucky.)