# How to save an object state from an external dll in c#

Tags: c#, dll

I know about XML serialization and it's how i save any object to a file when i need to do so, but i need first to access object's class code to add the xml serialization code.

What if the class is from an external dll and contains lots of objects contained in the dll, so i can't access internal code to add xml serialization tags to the class, **how to save its state to a file when i don't have access to its source code?**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Just change the `new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass));`  to `new XmlSerializer(instanceOfTheirObject.GetType());`

Comment: I don't have access to the source code of a certain dll, i use some classes from this dll, one objects of these classes needs too much time to be filled with the values that i need (it's a classifier that needs time for training).
After this training i need to save its state in order to not to waste time each time i run my program to repeat the training steps

Comment: @jeroenvanLangen shouldn't i need to add [serializable] attribute to the class and make sure that all attributes i want to save are declared as public ?

Comment: This isn't needed for the XmlSerializer. look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392431/why-doesnt-the-xmlserializer-need-the-type-to-be-marked-serializable

Comment: @jeroenvanlangen Thank you Sir
but i won't be able to save private data members right ?

Comment: With `XmlSerializer`, nope... you need a `BinarySerializer` or i has to implement `ISerializable` interface and do the job by it self.

Comment: I'm very thankful :) if you can post the final comment as my answer i'd be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

Unless each object has the [Serializable] attribute then you would need to make your own wrapper to go through each class and save everything you need to a file and then when you need it loading loop through the file and set all the values back to how they were.

If your lucky enough that everything you need to save is Serializable then you can do it in just a few lines of code.

Comment: Since you now say you don't have access to the source your only option really is to loop through each class saving all the values that you need to a file

Comment: what about private members? i can't save these members right?
Are there any code samples to do the looping? Thanks in Advance

Comment: No, you won't be able to save any private members.    Another option would be to decompile the dll and rebuild it using the code you get from decompiling. You may not be able to decompile it though, it all depends on the developer of the dll