# XML reading issues

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Im making a text based RPG, and I'm currently working on the save/load system.

Basically I save every state that is bound to the Player Object into an xml file and save any Item Object what is found in the players inventory into another xml file.

It creates the files, and I can read the first, but when it proceeds to the item, it gives me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll Additional information: Error in the
>   XML-document (2, 2).

The code what reads from the XML:

```
public class Item { //the item object
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Rarity { get; set; }
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public bool Equipable { get; set; }
    public bool Equiped { get; set; }
    public bool Usable { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
//The code whats read from the xml
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader2 = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Item));
System.IO.StreamReader xml2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(path + Path.GetFileName(file2));
Item overview2 = (Item)reader.Deserialize(xml2);
Item item = new Item();
item.Rarity = overview2.Rarity;
item.Damage = overview2.Damage;
item.Amount = overview2.Amount;
item.Price = overview2.Price;
item.Equipable = overview2.Equipable;
item.Equiped = overview2.Equiped;
item.Usable = overview2.Usable;
item.Description = overview2.Description;
Items.Add(item);
xml2.Close();
```

And the XML
[image]

Comment: Why do you deserialize the XML into an item, and then copy all the properties into another item? You can just use `overview2` directly here.

Comment: Post the definition of `Item` and also the xml...

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the right file?  As [this demo shows](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OagSI5), your XML deserialises with no problems.  The error implies that the first element name is incorrect (the inner exception would tell you more detail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers, I wasnt home for the weekend, but I found the solution.

In the :

```
Item overview2 = (Item)reader.Deserialize(xml2);
```

I was using reader instead of reader2, i changed it and now it works.
Damn mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: as Charles Mager has pointed out, the rules I've listed below are for the `BinarySerializer` and not the `XmlSerializer` (yeah thats confusing). The XmlSerializer just serializes all public properties.*

I'm not sure if I should delete this answer or not as it can clear up some confusion but isn't the right answer for this question.

The code looks good, but for XML serialization to work you need two more things

1. [Mark the class as serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx) using the `[Serializable]` attribute
2. Provide a parameterless constructor
3. Use properties with public setters (you've already fulfilled this criterium)

Note that an `Exception` often also contains an `InnerException` with more details on what exactly went wrong.

So this should work:

```
 [Serializable]
 public class Item 
 { 
        public Item() { }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Rarity { get; set; }
        public int Damage { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public bool Equipable { get; set; }
        public bool Equiped { get; set; }
        public bool Usable { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already added, the [Serializable] attribute what i forgot to include in my question.

The Player object looks and works the exact same way as the Item object, and the program can read from the players xml without any errors.

Tried adding a parameterless constructor too, like u just siad, but it keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: @TischlerKristóf Click "[Copy exception Detail to Clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx)" when you see the error then post the full text as a edit to your question. Also could you include a text version of the XML instead of a JPG so we can copy and paste it in to our own programs and test it.

Comment: The `[Serializable]` attribute has nothing to do with `XmlSerializer` and the public parameterless constructor is implicit.  This should give exactly the same error as before.

Comment: @CharlesMager you're right. There are so many serializer that all behave slightly different in .Net, its a mess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392431/why-doesnt-the-xmlserializer-need-the-type-to-be-marked-serializable

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:
    Item overview2 = (Item)reader.Deserialize(xml2);
The Item class defines a string Name, but that is not in the XML you are reading in.  My guess is that since the properties don't match the XML, you are getting the error.

Try adding a Name element to the XML (even if it is blank) and see if that solves the problem.